# Disable OPEN in SharePoint Online options?

Tags: list-view, sp-online

My company has a SP list for a staff directory called ***Who's Who***. All of the columns are visible in the **All Items** view except for 1 field -- the **Mobile Phone** number. That is only visible to the HR (and IT Development) staff using a view called ***HR-View***. I have confirmed that a general user cannot access the ***HR-View*** and that the column is not shown in **Quick Edit** mode.

There is 1 problem. A general user can select a person, then click on the ellipsis and choose **Open**. The fly-out opens and exposes the **Mobile Phone** number to the general users (a big no-no). Do I have to create a new fly-out for the view/edit forms, or is there a way to disable the **Open** menu option.

[image: ***enter image description here***]

FYI - the general user cannot edit the data in the fly-out because they are read-only, but that can read a column which we would prefer they not be able to see.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, SharePoint lists allow you to define the columns you want to have on them. That means you are able to create a model. Those columns are visible for all users with, at least, visitors permission. You can create views for helping users to read that information in easily ways like hiding columns, sorting columns, grouping, filtering and so on. The unique way of modifying the view and edit form is using external tools like SharePoint Designer (I totally dislike) and PowerApps. Explore this option and you will be able to set visibility rules for the field/s you need to hide based on the user.

I have to say that more 3rd party tools are available in the market for modifying forms, but those two I mentioned are the native ones.

Comment: OK, so I used PowerApps to create 3 new screens -- View, Edit, and New and I set them in the SharePointIntegration control. I save and publish back to SP and I'll wait and check later and I still get the same result. Using Chrome, with All Contacts view, if I select 1 employee, the click on the Details icon it shows the mobile number field... WTH? How do I shut this Details pane off?

Comment: Check if the solution provided [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Ideas/Override-SharePoint-lists-details-pane-with-customized-Power-App/idi-p/79759) fits you well for your issue. It's just configuration so let's see.

Comment: Jeff_Thorpe's comment about QuickEdit is useful to know, but not applicable to this situation. It is the Details icon which any user can click to see all of the columns regardless of their security access. The third comment by LiefFrederickson is more what I'm wanting.

Comment: Actually, Jeff responded to another post I had here:  https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Disable-the-Details-icon/m-p/341224#M97871 where he explains my solution very well. Thanks, Jeff!

Answer (score 0):

One option and probably the route I would take is to customize the right side panel using PowerApps (you can see the option up towards the ribbon when you open an item).

You can set a rule in there for only certain groups to be able to see that field.

Hope this helps!